# SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer: is it possible cancelling operation?

Tags: sqlbulkcopy

we transfers text file data to db using SqlBulkCopy object, especially by WriteToServer method.
We would allow user to cancel operation. Is it possible? How should we do?

SqlCommand has a Cancel command, but SqlBulkCopy has not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to cancel a Sql​Bulk​Copy.Write​To​Server (c#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44959735/is-it-possible-to-cancel-a-sqlbulkcopy-writetoserver-c)